# SElinux sandbox fails to start from systemd service

Tags: selinux, systemd

I have a server that runs user submitted code, for evaluation. 
I wrote a systemd service that starts a python application, that application then run the submitted code using SElinux sandbox.

The sandbox fails to start with the following error

```
/usr/bin/sandbox: User account must be setup with an MCS Range
```

However when I start my server from the command line as a normal user, instead of a systemd service launching it, it works without issues.

This is the output from `semanage login -l`

```
Login Name           SELinux User         MLS/MCS Range        Service

__default__          unconfined_u         s0-s0:c0.c1023       *
root                 unconfined_u         s0-s0:c0.c1023       *
system_u             system_u             s0-s0:c0.c1023       *
```

My knowledge of SELinux is very limited, Since it works when launched by a normal user I am guessing this has something to do with system_u?

Running Fedora 20.

The python application is actually a celery worker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues that cause this to fail.

### TL;DR

To get this to work, you need to:

1. Run `sandbox` with a `--level` option.
2. Install the policy I show below.

### Problem 1: MCS Ranges

When you start the service from the command line as a normal user, you are probably running in the following SELinux context.  You can verify with `id -Z`.

```
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

There are five parts to that context.

1. Your *SELinux user* (unconfined_u)
2. Your *role* (unconfined_r)
3. Your *domain* (unconfined_t)
4. Your *MLS range* (s0-s0)
5. Your *MCS range* (c0.c1023)

By default, the latest version of sandbox requires that the user executing the sandbox command has an MCS range defined (see [commit 78b077c](https://github.com/SELinuxProject/selinux/commit/78b077cd090a7b4a715aea0090eff20c748b796a) and [commit 6c2ad1c](https://github.com/SELinuxProject/selinux/commit/6c2ad1ce52e0bc215f9f5d460c881cf4325fb46e) from 2011).  When you're running as the normal user, everything's OK, because you have an MCS range defined.  However, look at the context that systemd services run in by default.  (I got this by making a script that printed out its SELinux context to the syslog.)

```
system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0
```

Whoops!  We don't have an MCS range!  This is why you got your error when running sandbox in a systemd service.

Fortunately, sandbox has a command line flag that you can use to explicitly set the MLS and MCS parts of the execution context: `--level`.  That is, when you run

```
sandbox --level "s0" /path/to/my/command
```

then sandbox will no longer attempt to extract your current context's MCS range.

### Problem 2: Sandbox Domain Pairings

If you make the above change and try re-running your service, however, you will get a new error.

> /usr/bin/sandbox: Could not set exec context to system_u:system_r:sandbox_t:s0. Invalid argument

That error means that SELinux will not let you transition from the systemd context to the sandbox context.  The reason for this is the pairings between the two different roles (system_r/unconfined_r) and the sandbox domain (sandbox_t).

The command `seinfo -rXXXXX -x` shows you a list of the domain pairings that are legal with the role "XXXXX".  Let's look for sandbox_t.

```
$ sudo seinfo -runconfined_r -x | grep sandbox_t
     chrome_sandbox_t
     sandbox_t
$ sudo seinfo -rsystem_r -x | grep sandbox_t
     sshd_sandbox_t
     chrome_sandbox_t
```

So, "sandbox_t" is available for pairing with "unconfined_r" but not "system_r".  I don't know why this is the case; my best guess is that the Red Hat people wrote sandbox with the intention of only normal users running it.  Fortunately, it's reasonably easy to add a pairing between "system_r" and "sandbox_t".  Create a policy file (*.te extension) with the following content.

```
policy_module(sandbox_system, 1.0);
require {
    type sandbox_t;
}
role system_r types sandbox_t;
```

If you name the file "sandbox_system.te", you can install it by running the following commands.

```
$ make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile sandbox_system.pp
$ sudo semodule -i sandbox_system.pp
```

Now, if you re-run `seinfo`, you should see the correct pairing.

```
$ sudo seinfo -rsystem_r -x | grep sandbox_t
     sshd_sandbox_t
     chrome_sandbox_t
     sandbox_t
```

Depending on your setup, you may need to add a few more rules to your policy file, but from this point forward, *setroubleshoot* and *audit2allow* will be able to do most of the work.

I hope this helps someone!